# Как правильно обновить mysql 5.6 до 5.7 в freebsd 10.2

Tags: mysql, freebsd

В портах появился mysql 5.7 в портах. Обещают существенный прирост в производительности думаю обновится. Как это правильно сделать с 5.6? В мануале mysql говорит обновите бинарники старой версии на новую. Если установить 5.7 из портов они перезапишутся?

Answer (score 1):

> Если установить 5.7 из портов они перезапишутся?

да.

чтобы не было неожиданностей, попробуйте сначала на тестовом окружении, например в виртуальной машине.